# Is there a standard name for this relation property : " aRb --> there is no c different from b such that aRc "?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Maybe this property could be called "exclusivity" ?

Does it have a standard name?

It recalls the definition of a function as a " single-valued relation" (Enderton).

But here, it is not required that any *a* ( in a given set) be related to some *b*.

Comment: It is referred to as being "*Well-defined.*"  Compare this to that every $a$ is related to some $b$ which is referred to by the phrase "*Everywhere-defined.*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I've never heard "well-defined" used in this sense. Whenever I've heard "the relation $R$ is well-defined," what's been meant is "the definition of $R$ we gave was in terms of representations of objects, but in fact different representations of the same objects don't yield different results."

Comment: @JMoravitz I see "Well-defined" as more of a term about functions. Plus, I would also expect a well-defined function to be defined on its domain. In the context of relations, calling this "well-defined" suggests that other relations (that are defined perfectly well) are not well-defined.

Comment: I don't know of a name, but I'd consider calling such relations "many-to-one" or "codomain-exclusive".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such relations are (in my experience) called "**functional**", in analogy with functions. Indeed, such a relation *is* a partial function (and actually I've heard "$R$ is a partial function" more frequently than I've heard "$R$ is functional").

Similarly, relations such that for every $a$ there is at least one $b$ with $aRb$ are called "**total**" (in analogy with partial vs. total functions), or ["**serial**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_relation) (although I've heard that one much more rarely). And relations such that for each $b$ there is at most one $a$ with $aRb$ are called "**injective**" (or "one-to-one") relations.

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?

Comment: Injective would mean here that if $aRb$ that there is no $c$ different than $a$ such that $cRb$.  This is a different condition than if $aRb$ that there is no $c$ different than $b$ such that $aRc$.  Every function satisfies the intended condition.  Only some functions satisfy the condition of being injective.

Comment: @NoahSchweber. Thanks for your answer. +1

Comment: @JMoravitz Derp, I'm an idiot - fixing! (I'm going to blame that one on math elves.)

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames See JMoravitz' comment (although I've fixed the issue now).

Answer (score 4):

According to [Encyclopedia of Math](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Functional_relation) and [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functional+relation), such a relation is called a *functional relation* on a set.

A functional relation defines a partial function from the set to itself, so you might as well call it a partial function.